# A better way of visualizing extreme oscillation curve in matplotlib?

Tags: neural-networks, python, data-visualization, matplotlib

Here are three curves. I'm training a model and trying to plot the training loss curve; the x-axis is iterations and the y-axis is loss value:

[image]

All the curves contain many spikes and noises. I'm interested in seeing which curve has less chaos ("less chaos" refers to less spikes or a smoother curve). One way is to use `np.convolve` to smooth the curve. Unfortunately, it lost so much information and defeat my original purposes. I'm wondering if there different way to visualize this? (Not necessarily plotting the curve differently, but using some mathematical method to visualize the smoothness in a different way.)

Comment: What are these data? What specifically do you mean by "less chaos" in this context?  Would that be just fewer spikes? The same number, but lower amplitude? Something else? Can you post your data, or a small example dataset?

Comment: @gung; "less chaos" refers to less spikes more smoother curve.  The data here. I'm training on some model and trying to plot the training loss curve : x-axis is iterations and y-axis are loss values

Comment: The nature of you data is unclear. Can you post the data, or a similar data set?

Comment: A dummy or a link help in evaluation.  You might ask what options there are to contrive the relative vertical slew per horizontal distance for horizontal step sizes greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common phenomenon when training neural networks with stochastic or mini-batch methods. Typical solutions include plotting only per-epoch averages (i.e. collecting results for all mini-batches and then averaging) or else using moving averages, smoothing, etc.

To avoid re-inventing the wheel, [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) give a nice way to log, plot and smooth results. If you use software like [TensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX), you can access the convenience of the Tensorboard interface even if you're not using Tensorflow to estimate the model.